# integrating CAS authentication on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, model, cas

I have integrated RubyCAS-Client from this github https://github.com/rubycas/rubycas-client It is working and bring up my CAS server for authentication... But the problem that I have is after inserting **before_filter CASClient::Frameworks::Rails::Filter** on my application_controller.rb, my model is not working and I could not add/edit/delete things from my model.

My Rails version is 3.2.6 and ruby version is 1.8.7.

Any help for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Under "Installation" on the readme for rubycas/rubycas-client it says this:

NOTE: For compatibility with Rails 3 have a look at
 http://github.com/zuk/rubycas-client-rails

Edit: That project has been moved to http://github.com/rubycas/rubycas-client-rails